# MongoHQ API: where is the _apikey/account secrete key?

Tags: mongohq

According the MongoHQ's [document](http://support.mongohq.com/mongohq-api/introduction.html) 
"[I] will pass your key as a params named _apikey for authentication."

But I could not find my api key, all I could find, after clicking my account's name on the right corner, is Account API Token. Are they the same thing?

I try https://api.mongohq.com/databases?_apikey=AccountAPIToken

But I got {"error":"Unauthorized"}.

Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks!!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I am also using Account API Token (As far as I understand this is the right one) but keep getting {"error":"Unauthorized"}.

Comment: Yes, the API Token is the right one, but the document you are looking probably is not the right one. Here's the doc http://docs.mongohq.com/mongohq-api-beta/documents.html

Comment: Thanks, apparently the regular API is not working and I should use the beta one. odd.